# ngModel value not reflected on view - changed in directive

Tags: angularjs, directive, angular-ngmodel

value set to false initially in controller

```
   $scope.isChangeUnsaved = false;
```

value in view

```
       Changes Status : {{isChangeUnsaved }} // false initially
```

i m trying to change the value of ngModel in directive. the value is changed but it is not reflected on view. here is my code i m using

```
       <form ngc-reload ng-model="isChangeUnsaved">
```

directive

```
    angular.module("biApp").directive("ngcReload", ["$parse","$log", function ($parse,$log) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        ngModel:"="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
        $JQ(".mainmenu a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
             scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.ngModel = !scope.ngModel;
                });     
             console.log("scope.ngModel",scope.ngModel); // Outputs true - value is changed
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

value not changed

```
                Changes Status : {{isChangeUnsaved }} // false even after changed in directive
```

Comment: Try changing "ngModel" to another word. I think that "ngModel" is a reserved word in the framework

Comment: @Pilot .. it does not work. ngModel already has isChangeUnsaved passed from directive attribute

Comment: bad idea putting an isolated scope directive on a form tag. Could have major issues with `ng-form` which is a complex directive. Why would you use `ng-model` also? That makes no sense

Comment: sorry sorry...I did read your code compettely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        angular.module("biApp").directive("ngcReload", ["$parse","$log", function ($parse,$log) {
 return {
     restrict: 'A',
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
        $JQ(".mainmenu a").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         ngModel.$setViewValue(true);
         ngModel.$render();
        });
     }
 }
```

}]);